# What is Hat on Web Applications site?

Tags: support

I got a new notification

> You earned Sufganiyot on Web Application!.

What is this "Hat"? You can see in my profile picture I wore this. Can anyone give a brief information about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a part of [Winterbash 2015](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/?cb=1)

> Starting now and going until the end of the day on Jan. 3, 2016, you'll once again be able to **earn and show off hats for all sorts of things you're already doing across the Stack Exchange network**.